# SQL Query to Iterate through one column values and fetching its count

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one table called "transaction_logs" in Oracle which contains the below columns :

1. job_id
2. logmsg_id
3. log_message
4. date_created

The data in this above table are like:

[image]

The Output I want to achieve from this Table from a sql query is :

[image]

**Could anyone Please help me to write a SQL query to achieve such type of scenario.
Thanks In Advance !!!**

Comment: There seems to exist no relation between the Processed messages and the process names. Btw, it's far better and preferable to add text data rather than images. Please share text data.

Comment: You can't get it, not with data you posted. Rows in a relational database table aren't ordered so - unless there's a column which says that ABC comes "first" and **its** "Processed msg = 17" follows, there's no way to do that. Maybe date column contains time component as well, which then sorts rows that way? Is there any other ID (sequence) column?

Comment: Yes There is a SEQ_ID column is there, Sorry i got to know little late.

Comment: Please let me know what will be the approach to achieve this with seq_id

Answer (score 0):

Guessing the date contains HH24:MI:SS, you could try this one, ... waiting for more info from you about the DDL:

```
select process_name, msg_count from (
    select 
        last_value(process_name) ignore nulls over(partition by job_id order by date_created) as process_name,
        last_value(qty) ignore nulls over(partition by job_id, process_name order by date_created)  as msg_count,
        date_created
    from (
        select 
            job_id, logmsg_id, log_message,
                case when instr(log_message,'Processed') = 0 then  log_message end as process_name,
                case when instr(log_message,'Processed') = 1 then to_number(regexp_substr(log_message, '\d+')) end as qty,
            date_created
        from data 
        where logmsg_id = 100
    )
)
where msg_count is not null
order by date_created
;
```

Comment: Hey Thanks For your answer, There is a column called SEQ_ID which is ordered, Could you please tell me what will be the way to achieve this by using SEQ_ID column?

Comment: uses it in the "order by" instead of the "date_created", always post the DDL of your tables with your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You need something that defines ORDER of the rows, so I'll assume a timestamp or similar in the DATE_CREATED

```
SQL> create table t ( j int, id int, msg varchar2(30), d timestamp );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into t values (123,100,'ABC',systimestamp);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values (123,100,'Processed Msg : 17',systimestamp);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values (123,100,'BCD',systimestamp);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values (123,100,'Processed Msg : 32',systimestamp);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values (123,100,'MNP',systimestamp);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values (123,100,'Exceeded limit',systimestamp);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values (123,100,'Processed Msg : 28',systimestamp);

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> select
  2    case when length(msg) = 3 then msg end tag,
  3    case when msg like 'Processed%' then substr(msg,18) end prc
  4  from t
  5  order by d;

TAG                            PRC
------------------------------ ----------------------------------------------------
ABC
                               7
BCD
                               2
MNP

                               8

7 rows selected.

SQL>
SQL> select tag, prc
  2  from (
  3  select d, lead(prc ignore nulls) over ( order by d ) as prc,
  4   tag
  5   from (
  6  select
  7    d,
  8    case when length(msg) = 3 then msg end tag,
  9    case when msg like 'Processed%' then substr(msg,18) end prc
 10  from t
 11  )
 12  )
 13  where tag is not null
 14  order by d;

TAG                            PRC
------------------------------ ----------------------------------------------------
ABC                            7
BCD                            2
MNP                            8
```

Comment: Hey Thanks For your answer, Yes there is a column called SEQ_ID which is ordered, Could you please tell me what will be the way to achieve this by using SEQ_ID column?

Answer (score 0):

Using `regexp_replace` to extract numbers from `log_message` then we use `LEAD` to get the extracted data from the next row :

```
With cte as (
  select LOG_MESSAGE AS Process_Name, LEAD(Log_Msg ignore nulls) over (order by DATE_CREATED) as Msg_Count
  from (
    select t.*, regexp_replace(LOG_MESSAGE, '[^0-9]', '') as Log_Msg
    from mytable t
  )
)
select *
from cte
where length(PROCESS_NAME) = 3
```

This is an other way to do it without `WITH cte` :

```
select *
from (
  select LOG_MESSAGE AS Process_Name, LEAD(Log_Msg ignore nulls) over (order by DATE_CREATED) as Msg_Count
  from (
    select t.*, regexp_replace(LOG_MESSAGE, '[^0-9]', '') as Log_Msg
    from mytable t
  )
)
where length(PROCESS_NAME) = 3
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Eopc3Y6P)

Comment: Hey Thanks For your answer, Can we make all this in a single Select Query ? and there is a column called SEQ_ID which is ordered, Could you please tell me what will be the way to achieve this by using SEQ_ID column too?

Comment: You can use `SEQ_ID` instead of using  `DATE_CREATED` in the  Order clause, `LEAD(Log_Msg ignore nulls) over (order by SEQ_ID)`